# Missing right Paranthesis on Create Table command SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

When creating the below tables I get the error message

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

```
create table CustomerOrder (
    CustomerOrderNumber NUMBER(15) CONSTRAINT Customer_Order_Number_pk PRIMARY KEY
    Customer_Number         NUMBER(7), CONSTRAINT Customer_Number_fk FOREIGN KEY,
    Order_Date              Date(6) CONSTRAINT Order_Date_not_null NOT NULL,
    Order_Status        VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT Order_Status NOT NULL,
    Order_Total          NUMBER(20) CONSTRAINT Order_Total NOT NULL
);
```

> ERROR at Customer_Number:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
create table Work_Order (
    Work_Order_Number   NUMBER(20) CONSTRAINT Work_Order_Number_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    Product_Number      NUMBER(20),
    Work_Order_Date     Date(9) Work_Order_Date_not_null NOT NULL,
    Date_Required       Date(9) CONSTRAINT Date_Required_not_null NOT NULL,
    Date_Completed      Date(9) CONSTRAINT Date_Completed_not_null NOT NULL,
    Work_Status         VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT Work_Status_not_null NOT NULL,
    Instruction         VARCHAR2(500) CONSTRAINT Instruction_not_null NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Product_Number_fk FOREIGN KEY (Product_Number) REFERENCES Product(Product_Number)
);
```

> ERROR at Work_Order_Date:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I tried to fix it here by putting the constraint for foreign key at the end but still does not work.

```
create table Work_Order (
    Work_Order_Number   NUMBER(20) CONSTRAINT Work_Order_Number_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    Product_Number      NUMBER(20), CONSTRAINT Product_Number_fk FOREIGN KEY(Product_Number) REFERENCES Product(Product_Number),
    Work_Order_Date     Date(9) Work_Order_Date_not_null NOT NULL,
    Date_Required       Date(9) CONSTRAINT Date_Required_not_null NOT NULL,
    Date_Completed      Date(9) CONSTRAINT Date_Completed_not_null NOT NULL,
    Work_Status         VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT Work_Status_not_null NOT NULL,
    Instruction         VARCHAR2(500) CONSTRAINT Instruction_not_null NOT NULL
);
```

> ERROR at Work_Order_Date:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

What are the changes I need to make in order to create these tables?
Where do I need to add the parenthesis?

This is for a piece of coursework about a jewellery shop database. The tables contain information about the business.

Expected result when run on SQL:

table created

Comment: Try to see some examples here, https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/create_table.php

Comment: `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` doesn't always mean there's an unbalanced parenthesis. It means there's a syntax error, in which the compiler has found an unexpected character. For instance, when we miss a comma at the end of a column declaration and start a new column declaration. Or when we define a column with datatype `DATE(9)`. Dates in Oracle are just `DATE` .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to remove commas after your column definitions and before CONSTRAINTS, unless it's at the end. it should be:

```
CustomerOrderNumber NUMBER(15) CONSTRAINT Customer_Order_Number_pk PRIMARY KEY Customer_Number NUMBER(7) CONSTRAINT
```

reference https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/create_table.php

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of all of the totals and not knowing explicitly what you are after, here are some samples that should help you get going

```
SQL> create table CustomerOrder (
  2      CustomerOrderNumber NUMBER(15) ,
  3      Customer_Number         NUMBER(7),
  4      Order_Date              Date NOT NULL,
  5      Order_Status        VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  6      Order_Total          NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
  7      CONSTRAINT Customer_Order_Number_pk PRIMARY KEY ( CustomerOrderNumber )
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create table Work_Order (
  2      Work_Order_Number   NUMBER(20),
  3      Product_Number      NUMBER(20),
  4      Work_Order_Date     Date NOT NULL,
  5      Date_Required       Date CONSTRAINT Date_Required_not_null NOT NULL,
  6      Date_Completed      Date CONSTRAINT Date_Completed_not_null NOT NULL,
  7      Work_Status         VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT Work_Status_not_null NOT NULL,
  8      Instruction         VARCHAR2(500) CONSTRAINT Instruction_not_null NOT NULL,
  9      CONSTRAINT Work_Order_Number_pk PRIMARY KEY ( Work_Order_Number )
 10  );

Table created.
```