# Getting an error that I'm missing a right paren when I am not

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting an error when creating two tables that I'm missing a right paren on the second table although I am not.

I've tried different oracle variations of this code and I'm still getting the error.

(ORACLE LIVE SQL)

```
CREATE TABLE PET_OWNER 
    (OwnerID    Integer Primary Key,
    OwnerLastName   Char(25)    Not Null,
    OwnerFirstName  Char(25)    Not Null,
    OwnerPhone  Char(25)    Null,
    OwnerEmail  Char(50)    Not Null);

CREATE TABLE PET_DATA
    (PetID Integer Not Null,
    PetName Char(50)    Not Null,
    PetType Char(25)    Not Null,
    PetBreed Char(50)   Not Null,
    PetDOB  Varchar(50) Not Null,
    Primary Key (PetID)
    Constraint FK_PetOwner Foreign Key (OwnerID)
    References Owner(OwnerID));
```

I expect the tables to be created but only the first table is being created successfully. The second table has a foreign key.

Comment: You are also missing the `OwnerID` column on the second table.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of another question about ORA-00907. I urge you to read [my comment on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669354/missing-right-paranthesis-on-create-table-command-sql#comment98027322_55669354).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a comma after the primary-key definition on the second table.

The Oracle parser often complains about missing closing parentheses when the real issue is some other syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
CREATE TABLE PET_OWNER (
    OwnerID    Integer Primary Key,
    OwnerLastName   varchar2(25)    Not Null,
    OwnerFirstName  varchar2(25)    Not Null,
    OwnerPhone  varchar2(25)    Null,
    OwnerEmail  varchar2(50)    Not Null
);

CREATE TABLE PET_DATA (
    PetID Integer Not Null,
    OwnerID Integer,
    PetName varchar2(50)    Not Null,
    PetType varchar2(25)    Not Null,
    PetBreed varchar2(50)   Not Null,
    PetDOB  varchar2(50) Not Null,
    Primary Key (PetID),
    Constraint FK_PetOwner Foreign Key (OwnerID) References Pet_Owner(OwnerID)
);
```

This fixes small problems (missing `OwnerId` column in the second table, wrong table name).  It also uses `varchar2()` for variable length strings rather than `char()` -- which are padded with spaces to the specified length.